How to fix UVs of spline tunnel/cylinder mesh?
I have created a tunnel using unity's spline tool. And I'm creating a custom shader for it in shader graph, and I would like to add bumps inside of the tunnel. The problem is in how the UVs, vertices and triangles are set up in the mesh:

But I would like to have the UVs and vertices be something like this:

Then I could easily sample a texture or generate a noise pattern.

It's not entirely clear what you're asking because you have a screenshot of how you want the UV map to look, but not how it looks now. Are you just wanting to convert tris to quads? You can do that with Alt-J. But be aware that you can UV map tris just as easily as quads, and Unity will convert the quads back to tris anyway.
